# XPath to select elements that contain only text

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there a query that selects `<td>`s that only contain text, or are empty?

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Select</td>
    <td>me</td>
    <td>
        <label>but</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button>not</button>
        <button>me</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="orMe" id="orMe">
        <label for="orMe">or me</label>
    </td>
    <td>Select me, too!</td>
</tr>
```

I have searched Google, [and this cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/xpath), but my search thus far has returned null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//td[not(*)]
```

will select all `td` elements that ***have no element children***,

```
<td>1</td>
<td>Select</td>
<td>me</td>
<td>Select me, too!</td>
```

as requested.